# TensorFlow Checkpoint variables not saved

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, checkpoint

I am trying to use `Checkpoint` for my model. Before that tried this with a toy example. This runs with no errors. But every time I run, looks like the training parameter starts from the initial value. Not sure if I am missing something here?  Following is the code im using:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.range(10.)
Y = 50.*X
    
class CGMM(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.beta =  tf.Variable(1. , dtype=np.float32)

    @tf.function
    def objfun(self):
        beta = self.beta
        obj = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(beta*self.X - self.Y))
        return obj

    def build_model(self,X,Y):
        self.X,self.Y=X,Y
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.5)
        ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1),model =self.objfun ,optimizer=optimizer)
        manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, './tf_ckpts_cg', max_to_keep=3)

        ckpt.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
        if manager.latest_checkpoint:
            print("Restored from {}".format(manager.latest_checkpoint))
        else:
            print("Initializing from scratch.")

        for i in range(20):
            optimizer.minimize(self.objfun,var_list =  self.beta)
            loss, beta = self.objfun(), self.beta
            # print(self.beta.numpy())
            ckpt.step.assign_add(1)
            if int(ckpt.step) % 5 == 0:
              save_path = manager.save()
              print("Saved checkpoint for step {}: {}".format(int(ckpt.step), save_path))
              print("loss {:1.2f}".format(loss.numpy()))
              print("beta {:1.2f}".format(beta.numpy()))

        return beta


model =CGMM()
opt_beta = model.build_model(X,Y)
```

Results 1st run:

```
Initializing from scratch.
Saved checkpoint for step 5: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-1
loss 56509.74
beta 5.47
Saved checkpoint for step 10: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-2
loss 48354.54
beta 8.81
Saved checkpoint for step 15: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-3
loss 42085.54
beta 11.57
Saved checkpoint for step 20: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-4
loss 36750.57
beta 14.09
```

Results 2nd run:

```
Restored from ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-4
Saved checkpoint for step 25: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-5
loss 54619.16
beta 6.22
Saved checkpoint for step 30: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-6
loss 46997.79
beta 9.39
Saved checkpoint for step 35: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-7
loss 40958.30
beta 12.09
Saved checkpoint for step 40: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-8
loss 35763.21
beta 14.58
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's the issue :**

The main issue is that your `beta` variable is not trackable: it means that the checkpoint object will not save it. We can see that by inspecting the content of the checkpoint with the following function :

```py
>>> tf.train.list_variables(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tf_ckpts_cg/')

[('_CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH', []),
 ('optimizer/decay/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/iter/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/learning_rate/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/momentum/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/rho/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('save_counter/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('step/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', [])]
```

The only `tf.Variable`s tracked by the checkpoint are the one from the optimizer and those used by the `tf.train.Checkpoint` object itself.

---

**A possible solution :**

To change that, you need to track your variable. The TensorFlow documentation about that subject is not great, but after searching a bit, you can read the following in the [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) documentation :

> Variables are automatically tracked when assigned to attributes of
> types inheriting from tf.Module.
>
> [...]
>
> This tracking then allows
> saving variable values to training checkpoints, or to SavedModels
> which include serialized TensorFlow graphs.

So, by making your CGMM class inherits from `tf.Module`, you can track your `beta` variable, and restore it! Here's a really straightforward change to your code :

```
class CGMM(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CGMM, self).__init__(name='CGMM')
        self.beta =  tf.Variable(1. , dtype=np.float32)
```

We also need to tell the `Checkpoint` object that the model is now the CGMM object:

```
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1) ,model=self, optimizer=optimizer)
```

Now if we train for a few steps and look at the content of the checkpoint file we get something promising. The beta variable is now saved:

```
>>> tf.train.list_variables(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tf_ckpts_cg/'))

[('_CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH', []),
 ('model/beta/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('model/beta/.OPTIMIZER_SLOT/optimizer/rms/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/decay/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/iter/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/learning_rate/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/momentum/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('optimizer/rho/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('save_counter/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', []),
 ('step/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE', [])]
```

And if we run the program a few times, we get:

```
>>> run tf-ckpt.py

Restored from ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-28
Saved checkpoint for step 145: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-29
loss 0.00
beta 49.99
Saved checkpoint for step 150: ./tf_ckpts_cg/ckpt-30
loss 0.00
beta 50.00
```

Hurray!

---

**Note**: In order to track variables, you can also use any kind of `keras.layers.Layer` as well as any `keras.Model`. It is probably the easiest way.

An extract from the [Training Checkpoint guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint?hl=en#saving_from_tfkeras_training_apis) :

> Subclasses of tf.train.Checkpoint, tf.keras.layers.Layer, and
> tf.keras.Model automatically track variables assigned to their
> attributes.